# Java 8 : How to find kth smallest, efficiently

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

In java 8 how do I find the Kth smallest efficiently? Kth smallest is

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/

I've attempted below. If there is a **more efficient solution** which provides securities of Java-8 such as I should not have to check size before accessing indices in case of an empty array etc. I believe that my own solution is safe against empty array.

A **provable time complexity comparison** of my Java-8 approach and a better Java-8 approach will be appreciated if there exists one. Thank you.

```
package lab.rat.jerry.kthsmallest;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class KthSmallest {

    // Inputs
    static int k = 3;

    static Integer[] myIntArray = {2, 3, 1, 4, -2, 0, -3, 0, -1, 5 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(myIntArray);

        System.out.println(list
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .distinct()
            .limit(k)
            .skip(k-1)
            .collect(toList())
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sorting your input, which means your running time is O(nlog(n)). If I remember correctly, the best algorithm to find the k'th smallest (or largest) element takes O(n) time. The algorithm is similar to Quicksort, but runs faster, since it doesn't have to sort the entire input.

Comment: I'm not sure that question about **time complexity analysis** is proper for this site. It's better to go to cs or codereview subsite

Comment: You can use a sorted collection like TreeSet. You can insert each element and remove the smallest when the size exceeds k. Note: this will drop duplicates, which you can correct for by making every element different.

Comment: Why do you collect a single element into a `List`?

Comment: This is an algorithmic question, so should be asked on cs.

Comment: What @Eran means, is [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). Regarding the actual question, there is no *java-8 specific* improvement. The `TreeSet` based solution mentioned by Peter Lawrey is easier to implement and still better than the Stream based approach. But like quickSelect, it’s still not Java 8 specific.

Comment: Your code is quadratic. Once sorted you already have in k-th position the k-th smallest element. No need to re-sort at each iteration. Beside that, obtain k-th smallest element can be achieved in O(n)

Comment: @Eran thanks, I was looking for a more Java-8 oriented answer e.g. while using java 8 how can I efficiently find kth smallest. with all the benefits of not worrying about accessing an index while array is empty etc.

Comment: @Holger, Yes I can collect the single element instead of string, thanks, for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks, @Andremoniy I will look else where as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Jeronimus I will look else where as well.

Comment: I will update the question to have a clearer goal

Comment: @Holger, I suggested more optimal implementation for `sorted().limit()` operation chain, though it was probably too late for Java 9 (see [JDK-8153332](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153332)). Maybe I should try to revive this for another review round in Java 10...

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: well, there are so many unused opportunities for fusing operations…

Comment: The typical approach to k-smallest is any kind of PriorityQueue. There are various implementations but all of them solve this optimally (Theta) in general. So just fill a PriorityQueue and then poll k items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Data Structure `PrioretyQueue` in Java. You can fastly get and remove the Largest or the Smallest element:

```
public static int kthLargestElement(int[] nums, int k) {

    PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++) {
        queue.add(nums[i]);
    }
    while (k > 1){
        queue.poll();
        k-=1;
    }
    return queue.poll();
}
```

Comment: You method returns the element based on position.  What about duplicate elements?

Comment: This method found the kth largest element in an unsorted array. This will be the kth largest element in sorted order, not the kth distinct element.

Comment: I understand that.  But the OP used distinct in their code so I presumed duplicates were of concern.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Yep, it working for duplicates also. In my case (Question from codesignal.com to find KTh larger element ) it works efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how efficient this is but it takes into consideration if:

1. The array contains duplicate values.
2. k is greater than the final list.

```java
      int k = 4;
      int[] numbs = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,10,11,12
      };

      int smallest =
            Arrays.stream(numbs).distinct().sorted().skip(k - 1).limit(
                  1).findFirst().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

      System.out.println(smallest);
```

1. This converts the array to a stream.
2. removes duplicates
3. sorts whats left.
4. skips the first k-1 values.
5. limits the rest of the list to one
6. Returns it.

If k is too large, the minimum int value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
package lab.rat.jerry.kthsmallest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class KthSmallest {

       // Inputs
      static int k = 3;

      static Integer[] myIntArray = {2, 3, 1, 4, -2, 0, -3, 0, -1, 5 };

      public static void main(String[] args) {

         List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(myIntArray);

         int smallest = list.stream()
                            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                            .sorted()
                            .limit(k)
                            .skip(k-1)
                            .findFist()
                            .getAsInt();
         System.out.println(smallest);
     }
}
```

By using this approach you can avoid NullPointerException. because `findFist()` will return optional.

Hope it help :)

Comment: Please note that it is not using distinct (though its not that important). Please note that my own code is also safe against empty array. Please note that time complexity related information is not in the answer. Can you please share some more details?

Comment: There is no real difference to the code that is already contained in the question. Since the question’s code already selects a single element, there is no sense in appending a `min()` operation, a simple `findFirst()` would do as well. Or just `forEach(System.out::println)`.